# RStudio, pdflatex fail on .tex file

Tags: pdftex, rstudio

I have compiled many .pdfs and knit many .Rnws and .Rmd files in the past with this computer. Not sure what changed, but I now get a message stating:

`Running pdflatex.exe on [doc_name].tex...failed`

I checked my environment variable, `PATH` and it seems to be defined correctly, as indicated in the screenshot below. I checked to see that `pdflatex.exe` actually exists in the `PATH` I specified; it does. Curiously, though, I ran `Sys.which('pdflatex')` in RStudio's console and a weird path is listed: It says `MIKTEX~1.9`. That looks incorrect, as I have `MikTeX 2.96615` installed. Is that the issue, or is that fine? I'm not sure if the tilde serves as a wildcard or something, or if this is the problem. I've looked through several SE posts and RStudio forum posts without luck.

If it is the problem, how do I fix it?

I also tried `Sys.getenv()` in the RStudio console and it seems like the correct path is there:

```
PATH C:\Users\andcy\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\
```

[image]

The output of `pdflatex -version` in a `cmd`:

```
C:\Users\andcy>pdflatex -version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6607 (1.40.18) (MiKTeX 2.9.6600 64-bit)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2018 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.56.1; using libcurl/7.56.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2; using expat_2.2.0
compiled with jpeg version 9.2
compiled with liblzma version 50020032; using 50020032
compiled with libpng version 1.6.34; using 1.6.34
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.5.3; using LibreSSL 2.5.3
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 2.6592; using 2.6592
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 5.6594; using 5.6612
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 1.6584; using 1.6584
compiled with poppler version 0.60.1
compiled with uriparser version 0.8.4
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

When I `cd` to the directory of my `.tex` file and running `pdflatex` on it, I get citation warnings (need to run `pdflatex` again) and an undefined control sequence for `\emphasize{need}`.

Comment: Do you have several TeX distributions installed ?

Comment: I don't believe so. I never installed MiKTeX 1.9.

Comment: What are the output of `pdflatex -version` and `pdflatex yourfile.tex` from a terminal ?